# How to limit number of connections to one database on MySQL

Tags: mysql, connection

I am search in MySQL user connection limit in particular database, we got option user connection limit in overall database but not find any step which is provide connection limit on particular database level, if any one have some solution please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the 'account' level limitations:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html

You should already have a user for that database, and you can then set

```
MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR <number>
MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR <number>
MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR <number>
MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS <number>
```

from a GRANT statement. (You dont need all of them, maybe just MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS)

Answer (score 0):

log in to your server as `root` user 
go to `phpmyadmin` in `variables` section you can change

```
MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS
```

to a bigger number