# How can I limit connections to AWS RDS based on credentials?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We're heavily using RDS, and as a defence mechanism, I'd like to limit to what extent each service can hammer a database. What I'm thinking is this:

- limit incoming connections to 5 based on IP address (could be done with `iptables` on a regular EC2 instance)
- MySQL credentials - ie 5 connections from the batch system, 15 from UI, 6 from back office, etc

I can't find any documentation that helps me achieve this.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a RDS question, but MySQL question.
Create user per service used, then use following syntax (taken directly from the docs):

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost'
WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 500 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 100;
```

For full reference look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html)

Comment: Also, should probably mark as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720175/how-to-limit-number-of-connections-to-one-database-on-mysql

Comment: So you're saying that RDS adds no features usable to this goal, and that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html is the documentation for resource limiting per account.

Comment: No features I know of, although AWS team pushes new stuff out fairly often, so I wouldn't be surprised if they added something I do not know of. For now only AWS Redshift has better control through Workload Manager, I haven't seen anything similar for RDS.
If you find this answer enough, please either mark it as answered or close as duplicate.